# How do I get Nuget 2.x to run solution level package Init.ps1's?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a few solution level NuGet packages attached to a Visual Studio 2010 solution via .nuget/packages.config.

These packages each contain a Init.ps1 file. I'm trying to pre-install the packages via commandline or script on my CI server. Running `nuget install .nuget\packages.config -o packages` pulls the packages down into the packages folder. But it does not run the Init.ps1 scripts.

If I attempt and msbuild call on the solution file, it fails because required files installed by the package Init.ps1 files are not in place yet.

If I open up the solution in Visual Studio, the packages run Init.ps1.

How can I get the Init.ps1 files to fire along with the package install from a commandline/script without having to open Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is fake it. Run the scripts by hand by invoking PowerShell. But there might be problems with them. The $project argument passed to init.ps1 is a DTE object, and you can't make it available without a full copy of VS.